# Javascript - Is there a cdn link for the object spread polyfill?

Tags: javascript, polyfills, babel-polyfill

I'm searching a polyfill for the object spread operator in javascript. Does anyone have a cdn link or if not a way to do it with es5 javascript?

```
var i = {
  test: 123,
  test1: 5234
}

var b = {
  ...i,
  test3: 243
}
```

Comment: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread@7.0.0/lib/index.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is impossible. Object spread is *syntax*, so it cannot be polyfilled. Only new objects and methods can be polyfilled, but not new syntax.

However, you can *transpile* the code using Babel: http://babeljs.io/

```
"use strict";

function _objectSpread(target) {
  for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    var source = arguments[i] != null ? arguments[i] : {};
    var ownKeys = Object.keys(source);
    if (typeof Object.getOwnPropertySymbols === "function") {
      ownKeys = ownKeys.concat(
        Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(source).filter(function(sym) {
          return Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(source, sym).enumerable;
        })
      );
    }
    ownKeys.forEach(function(key) {
      _defineProperty(target, key, source[key]);
    });
  }
  return target;
}

function _defineProperty(obj, key, value) {
  if (key in obj) {
    Object.defineProperty(obj, key, {
      value: value,
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
      writable: true
    });
  } else {
    obj[key] = value;
  }
  return obj;
}

var i = {
  test: 123,
  test1: 5234
};

var b = _objectSpread({}, i, {
  test3: 243
});
```

Ugly, but it'll work, and can be done automatically.

For this particular case, you can [polyfill `Object.assign`](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/object-assign-polyfill@0.1.0/index.min.js) and use:

```
var b = Object.assign({}, i, { test3: 243 });
```

Comment: Oh, thanks for this information. I've been looking for some time now and couldn't find an answear. Unfortunately I don't using webpack to transpile the code, so I have to use the object assign.

Answer (score 2):

The spread/rest operator was not valid syntax previously.  You will need to transpile that syntax to something that is valid in order to use it.